# Calibre sets itself as the default app for everything - how to change that?

Tags: lubuntu, calibre

so I've been using calibre for e-books for a while, it's great, but it sets itself as the default application *for every filetype that isn't explicitly set* by another program.

This is very annoying, how do I change that? I've tried tingling a bit with MIME, but I find it daunting, I just don't know where to start. I'd like featherpad to be the default application, not calibre.

I'm on a Lubuntu machine, 20.04, and using the i3 windows manager. and would prefer some form of CLI way of doing it.

I installed Calibre with the tarball as per the instructions [here](https://calibre-ebook.com/download_linux)

Comment: You haven't provided release details; but https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/3.2/3.2.17/alternative_configurator.html (link relates to the latest *stable* release or 21.04; adjust as appropriate)   or https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/3.2/3.2.7/file_associations.html  (detail for most is found in `/etc/xdg/xdg-Lubuntu/mimeapps.list` or package `lubuntu-default-settings`)

Comment: sorry, corrected with version. The link does't help, however, since calibre will open all the files that does not have an application set.

Comment: Also, how did you install calibre. With apt or the standalone tarball from the calibre site?

Comment: updated question again :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok something like this seems to be the way to go - it's not a complete answer, but hopefully it'll help some ppl

Get mimetype and try to change it:

```
  mimetype=$( xdg-mime query filetype "$v1"); lolecho "$mimetype"
  xdg-mime query default "$mimetype"
```

open this with texteditor

```
$HOME/.config/mimeapps.list
```